# Problem with funds and incrementing counter

Tags: solidity, truffle, metamask, ganache

I am writing this app using Truffle and Ganache suite and I am having trouble with a certain transaction. Solidity ver is 0.8.3.

I am using metamask to connect the wallet and importing contacts from Ganache

```
contract FlightSuretyData {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 fundedAirlineCount = 0;
    mapping(address => Airline) public airlines;

    event AirlineFunding(address airline);


    function fundAirline(address airline, uint256 amount) 
        external
        requireIsOperational
        requireAirlineIsRegistered(airline)
    {
        airlines[airline].isFunded = true;
        airlines[airline].funds = airlines[airline].funds.add(amount);
        fundedAirlineCount += 1;
        emit AirlineFunding(airline);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}
}

interface FlightSuretyData {
    function fundAirline(address airline, uint256 amount) external;
}

contract FlightSuretyApp {
    FlightSuretyData flightSuretyData;
    uint256 AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE = 5 ether;

    function fundAirline() 
        external 
        payable 
        requireIsOperational
        requireHasSufficientFunds(AIRLINE_REGISTRATION_FEE)
    {
        if (flightSuretyData.getAirlineIsRegistered(msg.sender)) {
            payable(address(flightSuretyData)).transfer(msg.value);
            flightSuretyData.fundAirline(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }
    }
}
```

and on the frontend I am calling it like this

```
    fundAirline(amount, callback) {
        const self = this;
        console.log('connected account', self.connectedAccount);
        self.flightSuretyApp.methods.fundAirline().send(
            {from: self.connectedAccount, value: this.web3.utils.toBN(this.web3.utils.toWei("5", "ether"))}
            ).then((receipt) => {
                console.log(receipt);
                if (callback) {
                    callback()
                };
            });
    }
```

I can confirm that the address is correct, the contract's method is accessed with no problems, but for some reason, the funds are not transferred and my account from ganache is not charged the amount, also I get a revert error that i don't understand.
Also, all requires are passed and the function is not stopping because of modifiers

[image: truffle debug transaction]

Comment: From the error message we could say that `fundAirline` is reverting, but th code is fairly simple so I'd check the modifiers for a require statement.

Comment: The thing is, when a require statement is reverting the transaction, the string message is printed, so I know if a require would be the problem. But I don't get any error message except revert

Comment: We don't know because you haven't provided enough code to reproduce the error. It could be anything, did you try adding more gas when calling it?

Comment: I solved the problem, commented the  `fundedAirlineCount += 1;` line and it worked. Any idea why It didn't work with that line? Can it be a problem with gas price?

Comment: To check if it is a gas issue you could use some high gas value like 2M. The only way that `fundedAirlineCount += 1` reverts is if the operations overflows, fundedAirlineCount was MAX_UINT256.

Comment: @Ismael using higher gas did not solve anything. Any reason why incrementing a contract variable `uint256 fundedAirlineCount = 0;` could revert transaction? I also tried using SafeMath operation like this `fundedAirlineCount = fundedAirlineCount.add(1);`. I deleted all modifiers and requirements to be sure that's not the issue, and it seems that for some reason, I can't increment that counter

Comment: I tried the minimal code you provided after removing missing modifiers, and adding missing functions. It work fine in my computer, so if there's a problem it should be in the part you haven't provided or in your computer. Try updating or reinstalling truffle/ganache, deleting old artifacts from build/ directory. Check your front code to make sure it is using the latest abi and deploy address.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for your input, turns out, it was a front end problem, because of a typo i was not sending the correct amount of gas, so it was out of gas issue, like you initially suspected.